# How to fix badly negotiated salary?

Tags: salary, new-job, burnout

Last year I was on the edge of a burnout. In hindsight it was because I was working in a toxic workplace. But through lack of experience I was not able to see the red flags. There have been cases of burnout in my old company since I quit. 
In my old company, there was always finger pointing, and I was always told how bad I was, and my evaluation results dropped dramatically.

So, I was really in a bad psychological mood when I started looking for a new job. I accepted the first job offer although the job was not so much a fit (different stack, a lot of things I haven‘t worked with before), because I thought that the people were nice. Since I was really close to burnout, I evaluated myself very badly and negotiated a very low salary.

But I‘m not a junior anymore. I am actually a senior with a lot of experience and I got very positive feedback in the first few weeks in my new job. When I applied for the job, it was said that they are planning to hire at least two people. But now I was told that there will not be another hire for my position, since I picked up the new stuff so fast and can get so much more stuff done that what was expected from me. (I got this information from my team-lead not from my manager.)

This strive comes from the very supportive environment in my new company. I really like it there and I get along with the people very well. So, the job is really a perfect fit for me. But the low salary really started to nag on me. How can I get a higher salary without losing the job opportunity? (Currently I have only a contract till end of the year, with the option of a unlimited contract.)

Comment: I agree with Joe's answer, but make sure you get your priorities right. You can live with less money easily, but you cannot live with less mental health that easily.

Answer (score 24):

> So, the job is really a perfect fit for me. But the low salary really
>   started to nag on me. How can I get a higher salary without loosing
>   the job opportunity?

If the salary isn't what you need/want, then the job isn't a perfect fit.

Wait until the end of your current contract. Then, if an extension is offered, indicate the salary you require in order to stay. Point out how much you have picked up and the value you bring to the company.

If they can't (or won't) meet your salary needs, decline an extension and move on to a job that meets your salary requirements.